# Object of type 'TypeError' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, restful-url

I try to build API with Django rest framework

And I got Object of

```
type 'TypeError' is not JSON serializable
```

What should I do to fix?

Here's my `view.py`

```
class NewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            nba = query_nba_by_args(**request.query_params)
            serializer = NewsSerializer(nba['items'], many=True)
            result = dict()
            result['data'] = serializer.data
            result['draw'] = nba['draw']
            result['recordsTotal'] = nba['total']
            result['recordsFiltered'] = nba['count']
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, template_name=None, content_type=None)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, template_name=None, content_type=None)
```

Answer (score 14):

Django cannot convert Exception object to JSON format and raise error. To fix it you should convert error to string and pass result to response:

```
except Exception as e:
    return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, template_name=None, content_type=None)
```

Comment: I got error  "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"  when I entered http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/ but I can get data when i entered http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/1 How can i get complete data from  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/news/

Comment: @Ray try `return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)` instead of `return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, template_name=None, content_type=None)`

Answer (score 0):

first

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Change line

```
  return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, template_name=None, content_type=None)
```

for this

```
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result),content_type="application/json")
```

or use

```
 from django.http import JsonResponse

 return JsonResponse(json.dumps(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python exceptions are not json serializable.
It's failing in `try` because of some connection or content unavailable issue, then going into `except` block where you are passing exception `e` as it is to `Response()` so that is creating the issue. Solution - check the URL and also in except block convert exception `e` to string and pass to `Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, template_name=None, content_type=None)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
except Exception as exception:
    return HttpResponse(exception)
```